# Moving navigation menu all the way over

Tags: html, css

I want to move my navigation menu and the element underneath all the way over so there are no spaces. My website is marikastravels.com

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Post the relevant code, not your website address.

Comment: I don't know the code I am customizing a wordpress site and am not familiar with the code. I am a new web developer

Comment: Which navigation elements?

Comment: the footer and the header navigation as well as the element below the header navigation

Comment: You mean no spaces on the right and left? Or top and bottom

Comment: So expand it so that there's no space on right and left?

Comment: Yes! I want it expanded all the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you make separate divs for your header, footer, and body. The biggest problem is that `doc4` has `width: 96%` which is constraining the entire website. Best just make a different header so you don't have to override your body's width. Just set your header's width to `width: 100%` and you should be good to go! (After it's outside of the body, or `doc4` in your case)